# SVN auto-pros with Apache DAV

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, webdav

How can I set auto-props with SVN version 1.8 using the Repository Dictated Configuration?  http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config.  I am running svn server `svn, version 1.8.10 (r1615264)` and client TortoiseSVN 1.8.7 via HTTPS.

I tried setting up my configuration file as:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
* = svn:needs-lock=*
```

The configuration files I am changing are `/etc/subversion/config` and `/home/svn/repo/conf/svnserve.conf` but I'm not convinced these are the right files for Apache DAV access through HTTP/HTTPS.

When I checkout a repo and add files the svn:needs-lock is not getting set on the newly committed file.

Where does Apache get the SVN configuration file from?

Answer (score 1):

Read [the svn 1.8 release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config) and [SVNBook carefully](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto)! The feature is not about modifying client's runtime configuration but is about setting a versioned property in a repository.

- This feature works on client-side so it will work with any Subversion server version,
- The feature requires your users to use Subversion 1.8+ client, otherwise `svn:auto-props` versioned property won't have any effect.

You can set `svn:auto-props` value to `*.test = svn:needs-lock=*`  on the root of your repository (or repository path that represents a root of a project, it mostly depends on your repository structure). It will result into each file that matches the `*.test` pattern to have
`svn:needs-lock` property applied. See [SVNBook | Inherited properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.inheritable).